# Paypal - How to post additional data from paypal back to return_url?

Tags: php, paypal

I've been trying to integrate paypal into my website, but I ran into a problem. On my website, I'm selling products to customers without a need to register. Basically, a customer selects a product he wants and I get all the shipping information I need from paypal. So when my IPN returns `VERIFIED` status, I create an order for the customer and save it to the database. But now I want to give them a gift code when they complete the transaction. I know, I can just send the code in an e-mail, when the order is saved, but I'd like to show it to them, when they get redirected back from paypal to `return_url`. Since the order doesn't exist before they begin the paypal transaction and the gift code is created when they get redirected back, I don't know how to connect the gift code to their order. I figured I might be able to do it, if paypal sent additional data to my `return_url`, most likely a `transaction_id`. Is there any way to achieve such functionality, without me having to add another hidden input to my form? I don't want people to keep fooling with FireBug and changing the variables to what they want.

I implemented the IPN based on [this article](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/), and I save the order in the VERIFIED part, like this:

```
if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
  $data['Order']['first_name']=$_POST["first_name"];
  $data['Order']['last_name']=$_POST["last_name"];
  $data['Order']['email']=$_POST["payer_email"];
  $data['Order']['res'] = $res;
  $this->Order->create();
  if ($this->Order->save($data)) {

  }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {            
  }
}
```

So I get some info from paypal (first_name, last_name and payer_email). However, this happens in a SESSION between paypal and the website and not between the user and the website, so there's no way for me to declare a variable in the IPN and then read it when the user gets redirected from paypal to `return_url`.

Comment: Sorry, I may not fully understand, but is "gift code" your invention or a paypal feature?

Comment: A paypal IPN should have a "txn_id" variable. _The merchant's original transaction identification number for the payment from the buyer, against which the case was registered._

Comment: The thing is, paypal does not return any data back to return_url, only passes all the information to IPN, which are not connected in any way (or so it seems to me). I've read somewhere, that you could create another input before beginning the purchase and pass some data to it, that would be returned when the user is redirected back, but I don't want to pass any data which could be changed by editing the DOM.

Comment: Gift code is just a bonus, that the user gets when he completes the purchase. He can then play a little game and win a prize, but he has to enter the code in order to play.

Comment: I know about txn_id, but when the user is returned back to the website, there is no way of knowing, what was the id of the transaction, that he just completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I did not have PDT turned on on my Paypal account, after I turned it on, `transaction_id` was sent to my `return_url` using GET. Guess I should read more.

More on how to turn on PDT and how it works:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/

How `return_url` looked like:

`http://***/complete?tx=***&st=Pending&amt=***&cc=GBP&cm=&item_number=`

Answer (score 0):

> so there's no way for me to declare a variable in the IPN and then read it when the user gets redirected from paypal to return_url.

Yes, there is, you use the `custom` field, that usually is populated with the user_id from your database. You pass this to paypal in the form (POST) like this:
`<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="user_ID">`

Paypal will always include this data in any subsequent communication with you.

PDT in itself is not reliable! There is no guarantee the user will make it back to your site after payment (what if he hits the Pay button, gets the "Wait 10 secs before will redirect you back to the website" and at that moment the electricity goes off? You will never get the PDT data in the HTTP GET).

For this reason, Paypal recommends you implement **both** IPN and PDT:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/

With IPN, you are guaranteed to receive the notification, as it will be send multiple times until you reply "ok, I got it". In contrast, PDT is only sent once and only if the user makes it back to your website.

Comment: Thank you, but as I stated in the question, I did not want to post any data which might be editable by the user in browser. I create the order when paypal notifies the server about the payment and if user gets redirected back to the website (with a transaction id), I check the database and print him his coupon.

Comment: @Dygestor, hope I understood correctly what you mean, if you are concerned about the safety of the data being passed between your computer and Paypal, as the data is sent through POST, the user cannot edit it in the browser. You could of course use https as well. If I did misunderstood, please explain further.

Comment: Also not sure about the last part of your comment as you do not specify if you implemented IPN, PDT or both, but the user doesn't need to be redirected back to the website for the transaction to be successful. The user computer can explode right after the transaction is finished on the Paypal website, and Paypal IPN will stil notify you a successful transaction took place. Redirection to your website is only a nice to have, not mandatory for a transaction success! If you implemented your logic this way, it is incorrect. Hope that helps

Comment: If I used a hidden input like you suggested, the value of the input might be edited before it gets submitted. I implemented both IPN and PDT (as I stated in the question). Since the user was not logged in I was only able to display the gift code when he got redirected back from PayPal, otherwise his session might expire / cookie get deleted... If there was a different way to check his transactions when he visited the site after a payment was made, that would be perfect.

Comment: We should probably start a chatroom to discuss. Adding a hidden "custom" field is the correct way, as with both IPN and PDT you verify the data really comes from Paypal by sending the transaction ID back to Paypal who responds with the data again (for PDT). So there is not way anyone can tamper with the data as you suggest.